# react materialize sidenav trigger disappearing

Tags: reactjs, materialize

I am making an application using React and materializecss. I am trying to integrate a sidenav into my navbar. I have the desired markup and look, but whenever I add the 'sidenav-trigger' class to my menu button, the element itself disappears. I have no idea why it acts like this. I tried testing without the ComponentDidMount function, but the problem persisted. I also tried manually importing the materialize js through the index.html without any luck.

Here is my component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Header.css';
import M from 'materialize-css';

class Header extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    M.Sidenav.init(this.sidenav);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="header">

        <div className="navbar-fixed">
          <nav className="blue">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="nav-wrapper">


                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col s1">
                    <a href="#" className="sidenav-trigger" data-target= 
                    {"#" + "mobile-nav"}>
                      <i className="material-icons">menu</i>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col s3">
                    <a href="#" className="brand-logo"><span 
                    className="the">Super</span> Cool Brand</a>
                  </div>
                </div>


              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>

        <ul className="sidenav" id="mobile-nav" ref={(sidenav) => 
        {this.sidenav = sidenav}}>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here this is not normal practice in React.
{this.sidenav = sidenav}}>

Comment: that was someone else's solution to being able to initialize the sidenav in the ComponentDidMount function. They got the reference to the ul to be 'this.sidenav' and then initialized it with materialize's js.